# jQuery Chosen plugin - first option doesn't trigger change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

So I'm using the pretty nice jQuery plugin, Chosen; http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

What I'm doing is actually working with TWO Chosen style dropdowns in an 'either/or' fashion, ie the user needs to select an option from one OR the other.

So when the user selects one of the dropdowns, the other one (via javascript) gets set back to its default disabled value.

Both dropdowns are backed by ONE hidden parameter to actually hold the selected value, no matter which dropdown it came from. This is populated by having listeners on both dropdown's on the `.chosen().change()` event.

The only problem is, it doesn't appear to fire a "change" event when the user selects one of the first options in either dropdown, I guess as this appears to be the already selected option and is therefore not a "change". But both dropdowns actual first option (ie in the jsp) is a disabled option with the normal "Please select" text.

Is there a way to fire the change event even if the option selected was already selected? Or is there just a "select" event that fires even if there hasn't been a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use .trigger("change"), or .change() on your jquery object to manually trigger the change event.

Comment: The problem is that the Chosen plugin hides a lot of that away. The normal select object is not actually displayed and Chosen builds its own.

Comment: But when i used chosen, i can still trigger the events on my actual select object.Could you please show your code?

Comment: he is talking about adding $('#selectId').change() to your select after you change the value, to manually invoke the change event.

I'm getting the same error though. I'm using jquery.val() to change the value of the select. When I do that and then select the first option, it won't trigger the change event. If I select any other option though it will trigger the change event, as well if I select any other option and then select the first option, it will trigger the change event. I think manually setting the .val() isn't quite working.

Comment: If I don't use chosen for the select, it works. Hope that helps anyone troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
//Get the dynamic id given to your select by Chosen
var selId = $('your_select').attr('id');
//Use that id to remove the dynamically created div (the foe select box Chosen creates)
$('#'+ selId +'_chzn').remove();
//Change the value of your select, trigger the change event, remove the chzn-done class, and restart chosen for that select
$('#'+selId).val('your_new_value').change().removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
```

In a nutshell you are hard reseting chosen for your select. There might be an easier way than this, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem using Select2 plugin (remake of Chosen plugin).

I forgot the line "allowClear: true" when I 've declared the Combobox as a select2 one.

```
$('#selectLabelMap').select2({
                   placeholder: "Sélectionner un label",                 
                   allowClear: true    // <=  don't forget "allowClear: true (re-init the comboBox)
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the change first time when (DOM) is ready.

```
    jQuery(function ($) {

        $('#myselect').trigger("change");   

    });
```